# Cannot change iFrame content in Firefox 4/IE

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
        frame.id = 'myFrame';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(frame);
        var context = frame.contentWindow.document;
        context.body.innerHTML = 'testing';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This creates a simple iframe containing my text: 'testing'.

This works perfectly in Chrome, but Firefox and IE are rendering an empty iframe.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.id = 'myFrame';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(frame);

frame = (frame.contentWindow) ? frame.contentWindow : (frame.contentDocument.document) ? frame.contentDocument.document : frame.contentDocument;
frame.document.open();
frame.document.write('testing');
frame.document.close();
```

Javascript is interpreted differently by all browsers, so it's just a matter of using the common-approach.  This should work across all browsers.

Give it a try.

Comment: I've tried it as well before posting, and after reading your answer (just to make sure!). It's not the problem...

Comment: TNC - The new code does work nicely across browsers. Thanks. Any chance on how to add dynamic elements (like creating a script and putting it in the <head>)? I'm still having some trouble on that front...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  I don't mind helping with a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers explicitly prevent things like this so you can't, e.g., load somebody's bank website in a frame and interact with it in Javascript. This link:

http://spyder.wordpress.com/2006/05/31/hacking-around-firefox-security-in-order-to-actually-accomplish-something/

suggests that there are some bugs with how an empty iframe is initialized, and this one:

http://www.iframehtml.com/iframe-security.html

has some resources for how to deal with them.

Comment: This isn't even close to what the issue is.  This is on the same domain, and on the same page for that matter.

Comment: I'm aware of the XSS restrictions, but the iframe is created within this page, how do I control it's content? it should not be restricted because it's 'same origin', right?

Comment: Not at all, it's that's a cross-domain reference, and it's not even iframe specific.  Your issue stems from the right javascript being used.

Comment: The first link seems to be talking about an issue with empty `iframe` elements in Firefox, which sounds like it would affect your example. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote the last line innerHTML seems like a chrome only thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');        
    frame.id = 'myFrame';        
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(frame);        
    var context = frame.contentWindow.document;        
    context.write('testing');    
</script>
```

JS fiddle here confirms it's working in IE, Chrome and Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/mDMaj/